# perl regex matching, why is it not finding all matches, why is the order important?

Tags: regex, perl

I ran into a problem with perl's regex matching. I destilled it down to a small example on the command line. Why is the order in which the matches are attempted important here ?

1.

```
$ echo "XYG" | perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ m/X/gi) { print "Matches X\n"; } ; if ($_ =~ m/Y/gi) { print "Matches Y\n"; } ; if ($_ =~ m/G/gi) { print "Matches G\n"; } '
Matches X
Matches Y
Matches G
```

2.

```
$ echo "GXY" | perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ m/X/gi) { print "Matches X\n"; } ; if ($_ =~ m/Y/gi) { print "Matches Y\n"; } ; if ($_ =~ m/G/gi) { print "Matches G\n"; } else { print "No match on G\n"; } '
Matches X
Matches Y
No match on G
```

The 1. examples matches all three letters as expected, but the second example does not match the letter G, why ?

However if I create an intermediate variable, here named $aa:

```
$ echo "GXY" | perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ m/X/gi) { print "Matches X\n"; } ; if ($_ =~ m/Y/gi) { print "Matches Y\n"; } ; $aa = $_; if ($aa =~ m/G/gi) { print "Matches G\n"; } '
Matches X
Matches Y
Matches G
```

Then the match works again ?

My perl version is:

```
$ perl -e 'print "$]\n";'
5.022001
```

On a LM 18.2 machine

```
$ lsb_release -d

Description:    Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
```

Ty+BR
Max.

Comment: In short, whatever the pattern or the string, the regex engine tries to succeed and doesn't stop until the end of the string is reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if you match a regex in a scalar context like that, and you set the `g` flag (for global matching) it's iterative - that's to allow you to do things like `while ( m/somepattern/g ) {` and have it trigger multiple times.

That's because `g` means:

> g  - globally match the pattern repeatedly in the string

It'd not be particularly useful if it reset each time you tried it. But you can also use it slightly differently in an array context:

```
my @matches = $str =~ m/(some_capture)/g;
```

And that'll select them all into a list.

But with your code and regex debugging:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use re 'debug';

$_ = 'GXY';
if   ( $_ =~ m/X/gi ) { print "Matches X\n"; }
if   ( $_ =~ m/Y/gi ) { print "Matches Y\n"; }
if   ( $_ =~ m/G/gi ) { print "Matches G\n"; }
else                  { print "No match on G\n"; }
```

You'll get (snipped for brevity):

```
Matching REx "X" against "GXY" 
Matching REx "Y" against "Y"
Matching REx "G" against ""
```

The first match 'eats' "GX" to find "X", leaving "Y" for the next match, but nothing at all for the "G" match.

The simple workaround is omit the `g` flag, because then you're saying explicitly 'match once' and you'll get:

```
Matches X
Matches Y
Matches G
```

Alternatively, you can use the global match with a character class:

```
$_ = 'GXY';

my @matches = m/([GYX])/g; #implicitly operates on $_
print "Match on $_\n" for @matches;
```

Comment: Ty for the quick answer